# Object immediately destroyed after push_back'd into vector

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm not sure why this is happening but the following code is giving a runtime error because of a double destructor call:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class base
{
    public:
        virtual ~base(){}
};

template<typename T>
class derived : public base {
    public:
    derived(const T& t_){}
};

class myClass
{
    public:
        template<typename T>
        myClass(const T& t) : data(new derived<T>(t)){}
        ~myClass(){delete data;}
    private:
        base* data;
};

int main() {


    vector<myClass> vec;

    myClass obj(22);

    vec.push_back(obj); // constructor is invoked and then destructor is invoked, why?


    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/sLecwx

The "~myClass" destructor is being invoked immediately after pushing the object into the vector. Initially I thought of a temporary copy, but since the constructor is being invoked once it doesn't make much sense.. the same even happens if in the copy-constructor I take the object by value and not by reference

am I missing something here?

Comment: Google "rule of three" to find out why you must write an `operator=(const myClass&);` and a copy constructor `myClass(const myClass&)`

Comment: And "Rule of five" for C++11.

Comment: Or in this case, Rule of Zero, how you avoid writing all those by choosing better types for your members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MyClass` has neither a copy constructor nor an assignment
operator; both are necessary.  The object inserted into the
vector is a copy.  The default copy constructor makes a shallow
copy, which means that both instances end up pointing to the
same object.  Consider the rule of three: if you need a user
defined destructor, you generally also need a user defined copy
constructor and a user defined assignment operator.

Answer (score 1):

push_back takes a reference to an object but a copy of the object is made anyway when it is inserted into the underlying array.
This means the object's copy constructor is called, and you're actually pushing a copy of that object to the vector.

The original object is then destroyed when it gets out of scope.

Comment: `push_back` takes it's argument by reference, not value. However, a copy is made.  You should mention `emplace_back`.  C++11 also defines `push_back( T&& value )` for types which are move insertable.

Comment: @EdS. Since he has a constructed instance, `emplace_back` isn't really relevant.  And of course, it's only C++11, which means that most people can't use it yet anyway.  (On the other hand, the answer really should mention the rule of three.)

Comment: @EdS. push_back takes by reference into the push_back() method itself. The fact that there's no implicit temporary object doesn't mean there isn't a copy elsewhere. The copy is made to the vector itself.

Comment: @JamesKanze: So mentioning it is a bad thing because he has three lines of example code which don't fit it's use exactly?

Comment: @YochaiTimmer: Yes, I know, that's what I said.